# html dom text nodes

Tags: html, dom, dhtml

I am currently teaching myself the HTML DOM, and I have learned that (in order to create an HTML element) I must use `document.create` & `document.createTextNode`.  My question is whether all HTML elements require a text node?  Do image tags, form fields, or other HTML elements which don't display text have a textnode value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Text nodes are only required if you want text (other then that supplied through a property such as `HTMLInputElement.value`) in an element.